# jQuery setinterval in for loop0

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript infamous Loop problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem)

With the for loop, it does nothing. Without the for loop, it works perfect.

Without the for loop:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
  $("#k1").fadeTo(1000,0.01,callfunc).fadeTo(1000,1);
}, 5000);
var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
  $("#k2").fadeTo(1000,0.01,callfunc).fadeTo(1000,1);
}, 5000);
```

and so on...

With the for loop:

```
for(var i=1;i<7;i++){
  var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
    $("#k"+i).fadeTo(1000,0.01,callfunc).fadeTo(1000,1);
  }, 5000);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Read [Closures Inside Loops](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.closures).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @pimvdb pointed out you have closure (setTimeout creates one) inside loop, it won't work, you should have something like:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    (function(e) {
        var refreshId = setTimeout(function() {
            $("#k"+e).fadeTo(1000,0.01,callfunc).fadeTo(1000,1);
        }, 5000);
    })(i);
}
```

You may also want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem) for more information.

Comment: Maybe a typo with the parameter name not replaced? Line 4, 'i' not 'e'?

Comment: +1 @David19801: If you would like a little bit more descriptive way, you could use [this little helper function](https://gist.github.com/1908200).

Comment: At the time I made that comment, the parameter was called 'e' but line four referenced 'i'.. pimvdb has since made the edit I had in mind.

Comment: @JimBlackler: Yeah i realized that later but was fixed/edited by pimvdb :)